# How to use searchview to retrieve data from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I am trying to use searchview to show all matching profiles based on the characters input in search view by using the code below:

```
searchViewTexts = binding.searchViewExplore

searchViewTexts.setOnQueryTextListener(object: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

        if(searchViewTexts.isNotEmpty()) {
            databaseReferenceLokasi.startAt(searchViewTexts.query.toString())
                .endAt(searchViewTexts.query.toString() + "\uf8ff")
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            snapshot.children.forEach {
                                val searchedResults =
                                    it.getValue(SearchViewData::class.java)
                                if (searchedResults != null) {
                                    adapter.add(RecyclerViewSearchView(searchedResults))
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        binding.searchViewResultRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                    }
                })
        }

        return true
    }

})
```

And below is my recycler view holder code:

```
class RecyclerViewSearchView(val searchedResults: SearchViewData): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var uid: String
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
        viewHolder.itemView.name_for_search_view.text = searchedResults.namaUsaha
        viewHolder.itemView.city_for_search_view.text = searchedResults.longitude.toString()
        Picasso.get().load(searchedResults.coverImageUri).into(viewHolder.itemView.photo_search_view)
    }
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.search_user_eksplorasi_recycler_view
    }
}
```

But nothing show up from the recycler view regardless whatever I type in the searchView. What should be fixed in the code? Thanks

Comment: "But nothing show up" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?
Besides that, if you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) and [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-in-real-time-using-jetpack-compose-952abaab15c5) will definitely help. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks, I have read your article but the codes are exclusively for Firestore. The problem is when any character typed in a searchView box, some similar results will come out in the recycler view because it uses `\uf8ff` but the recyclerview never shows up and there is no error at all. What can be fixed from the code? Thanks.